# Stuck into logarithmic inequalities, need an advice

Tags: inequality, logarithms

There are some logarithmic inequalities that I cannot solve and would be very happy if you show me the way and explain a bit what should I do!
I hope they won't be a problem for you and you would help me!

$\left(x^2+x+1\right)^x<1$

$\frac{lg\left(11\right)-lg\left(-x^2-12x\right)}{lg\left(x+5\right)}>0$

$\log _{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}\left(6^{x+1}-36^x\right)\ge -2$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for the first one**

Since $\ln$ is increasing (preserves inequalities) you have

$$\left(x^2+x+1\right)^x<1\iff x\ln \left(x^2+x+1\right)=\ln \left(x^2+x+1\right)^x<\ln 1=0.$$

Now, $x\ln \left(x^2+x+1\right)<0$ implies $x$ and $\ln \left(x^2+x+1\right)$ have different sign. Can you get the sign of $\ln \left(x^2+x+1\right)$  in function of the sign of $x?$

**Hint for the third one**

$$\log _{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}\left(6^{x+1}-36^x\right)\ge -2\iff 6^{x+1}-36^x\ge 5=(1/\sqrt{5})^{-2}\iff 6^{2x}-6\cdot 6^x+5\le 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the help! I started solving it this way but got stuck somewhere...

Comment: Do you have any hints for the others?

Comment: I have included a hint for the third one.

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate your help! :)